# PHP process multiple form fields to checkbox field

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, field

I am trying to process data to a field with the API reference 'custom11746175'. However, this field has checkboxes and I want to process multiple values when necessary. Right now, I only have this, which will only process **one** of the values "Off-g", "On-g", "On-h" or "On-i" (the last defined one):

```
if (($_POST['custom13346240'] == 'Off-g')) {
$contactData['custom11746175'] = "Off-g";
}
if (($_POST['custom13346240'] != 'Off-g')) {
$contactData['custom11746175'] = "On-g";
}
if ($_POST['custom13500281']) {
$contactData['custom11746175'] = "On-h";
}           
if ($_POST['custom11746175'] == 'Yes') {
$contactData['custom11746175'] = "On-i";
}
```

What do I need to change in case I want to process **all** of the defined values (the number can vary) and have them marked in the checkboxes? Should I construct an array, to obtain something like a multidimensional field?

Comment: Please show us what's in `$_POST` and what you want to have from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah an array is what you need, if you put the double brackets [ ] after the `$contactData['custom11746175']` varaible is will add the new item to an array in `$contactData['custom11746175']` like this...

```
if (($_POST['custom13346240'] == 'Off-g')) {
    $contactData['custom11746175'][] = "Off-g";
}
if (($_POST['custom13346240'] != 'Off-g')) {
    $contactData['custom11746175'][] = "On-g";
}
if ($_POST['custom13500281']) {
    $contactData['custom11746175'][] = "On-h";
}           
if ($_POST['custom11746175'] == 'Yes') {
    $contactData['custom11746175'][] = "On-i";
}
```

Then to get the first element in the array you could simply do `$contactData['custom11746175'][0]`

Comment: thanks for helping. When I send this array to my CRM (Solve360), it only adds a (selected) option "Array" to the checkboxes, so it doesn't grab the elements. Any idea how I can let the CRM obtain the elements, or should that question go to Solve360 itself?

Comment: When you mean you "send this array to my CRM" are you using a Solve360 php library or something? Can you clarify this @MrOrange?

Comment: sorry for the lack of technical language. I am using the PHP script to send the data to Solve360, which has API references for every field. If I send one value to the field, Solve360 does process it correctly an marks it as checked in the list of checkboxes. However, an array appears as "Array" in the list instead of multiple checked checkboxes. If it´s not clear enough I understand and I start to think it is something to ask Solve360 about. But maybe you still have some ideas?

Comment: Do you have an API documentation link for what you are using on Solve360 that I can look at?

Comment: I am using [link](http://norada.com/answers/api/external_api_introduction) and the section "Contacts" on the right. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which URI are you working with? Are you sending it JSON? Can you post the data that you are sending to the URI?

Comment: Good day! Not quite sure what you are talking about here... All I have now is the Solve documentation myself.

Comment: I would post another question that pertains to the problem you having with Solve360. Seeing that the question I answered solves the original question you asked. Please check the answer as correct if it answered the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The team from Solve360 pointed out that the fields allow comma-separated values for multiple checkboxes. Therefore I changed the code above to this:

```
$items = "";

if (($_POST['custom13346240'] == 'Off-g')) {
    $items = $items . ',' . "Off-g";
}
if (($_POST['custom13346240'] != 'Off-g')) {
    $items = $items . ',' . "On-g";
}
if ($_POST['custom13500281']) {
    $items = $items . ',' . "On-h";
}            
if ($_POST['custom11746175'] == 'Yes') {
    $items = $items . ',' . "On-i";
}

$contactData['custom11746175'] = $items;
```

Hope that will help someone.